# JVM startup time using Equinox OsGi

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp, rcp, osgi-bundle, equinox

Is there any way we can log JVM start-up time in an RCP standalone app?

I tried to launch the app and verify the jars loaded using Procmon in Windows but did not get much idea about the JVM start up timings which I am guessing includes Java Jars and eclipse osgi bundles.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the JFR bundle listener could be of help. It will create events when OSGI bundles are activated and visualise the result in a flame graph.

See this blog post:

https://alblue.bandlem.com/2020/02/jfr-bundle-listener.html

It contains link to the GitHub project and a video showing how it can be used.